# How to check whether all fields in an object are 'false' while only one is 'true'?

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

I have an object with many boolean fields like so:

```ts
type SomeObject = {
  A: boolean
  B: boolean
  C: boolean
  ....
}
```

Is there an easy/efficient way to check if the `OR` of all other fields (besides a specified field) are `false`?

We can do it the brute-force way by just checking each field manually:

```ts
let foo:SomeObject = {
  A: false
  B: false
  C: false
}
let isA = !(foo.B || foo.C)
let isB = !(foo.A || foo.C)
let isC = !(foo.A || foo.B)
```

But I'm sure there is a more elegant way of accomplishing this.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? What are you going to do with the information that `isA`, `isB` and `isC` are all `true` because `A`, `B` and `C` are all `false`?

Comment: Although I don't see the actual use-case in this. `Object.keys()` (or `.entries()`), + `.reduce()`/`.every()` and a "skip" for the "specified field"

Comment: minor nitpick: you need a type that XORs properties, not OR's. Also - do you need this to be checked at runtime or compile-time? The former is not really about TypeScript, but the latter is possible - I can draft up an answer if that's the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need compile-time checking, it is very easy to do with a mapped type and an intersection (an identity mapped type thrown in for "prettifying" the generated type):

```ts
type SomeObject = {
  A: boolean
  B: boolean
  C: boolean
}

type OnlyOneTrue<T extends object, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K] : true
} & {
    [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: false
};

type Identity<T> = { [P in keyof T] : T[P] }

//{ A: true; } & { B: false; C: false; }
type test = OnlyOneTrue<SomeObject, "A">;

//{ A: true; B: false; C: false; }
type pretty = Identity<test>;
```

If you need compile-time *type guarding* so as the type can be narrowed later, then you need to use a union. The previous type can become a stepping stone for another utility type:

```ts
type PossibleOnlyTrue<T extends object> = {
    [P in keyof T]: OnlyOneTrue<T, P>
}[keyof T];

//OnlyOneTrue<SomeObject, "A"> | OnlyOneTrue<SomeObject, "B"> | OnlyOneTrue<SomeObject, "C">
type union = PossibleOnlyTrue<SomeObject>;

const process = (obj: union) => {
    //type is narrowed to a union member:
    if(obj.A) {
        console.log(obj); //OnlyOneTrue<SomeObject, "A">
    }
};
```

If you need runtime checks on top, there are options. Below is both a type and runtime guard based on the previous helper mapped types (`PossibleOnlyTrue` and `OnlyOneTrue`):

```ts
const runtime = <K extends keyof union>(obj: union, key: K) : obj is Extract<union, { [P in K] : true }> => {
    return Object.entries(obj).every(([k,v]) => k === key || !v );
};

{
    const obj:union = { A:true, B:false,C:false };
    if(runtime(obj, "A")) obj //OK, obj is OnlyOneTrue<SomeObject, "A">
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=42&ssc=2&pln=35&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgeQEYCsIGNhQLxQDeAUFFAIIBcUqccANhAIYB2pUAQtbQ822QGFudRq2IBfYsVCQoyFvRDyIAFQBOAVwgAeFVAgAPYBBYATAM5Q4GbMAA0UANL6jJi1ADWEEHABmUFQA%20fCJ2MgBtAAUoAEsWJwBdKGpgTQgJKAAyULII6LioAFEDLHoNUx0vH38VB0dAhOpfJnpzdPEAbikZaABJCpZgGNBdYIJCKCjY%20Kq-AKTqFSikyWIAejWJqihUrQ6ocSyiTiaWtv2hKGbWiH3JHp2Ic1wCeUVldS1teCQ0TBwHAAiciAwJddabCgpNL7LhXM63KCXa7nA7ScDQMBqCDAUAhfomIYjYzPMHdDFQSJwczmGKoRhvECfHR6QzGMyWaz-YBjHK5KYFWY1RpyBRKFiqNK6ByRQIScJC%20bgjaMj5Sn4oGwAqDA0FQAA%20oveEuZ30Qmu5QI4esNqpN6vNf1sQIEoPRsg0LBicHiBCpNLpDLFpo1TpwZOIWB9zygWLgWCelgIAAoudRPd6WABKfDBEi5KAbB4xSwsJhqNRwADuEFMOzgUCYUAzPqgSAQqAgakoYVivlTGAAdOQc-mC7koyxzLxB-Q4ABzAfoLP7FVitVfUNa%20w6kFyguSTpSScxzSDGJIELaZxstyWRUtliBJfpr0%20hxVaiOHPULmxSzFKkTA4Noj4OBMArxI4Cw7GkBxjHmvbYsAGhqPEYbAIOhJqDETxLlmWEAG5diAybJgqdiEQkOZ4MEHj4HgBBVAahoAISEVAK4SOCY5kCeuBpo%20IRbJQuwQA4XAouJQhSQcXQFjE-ZnkMSBLkCIJZjmf4qo4Dh-iWRripKm6Otu6luuIQA)